# Galvanic corrosion between silver plated MCCB terminals and aluminium

Tags: copper, corrosion, busbar

We are planning to install a switchboard in one of our garages. The MCCB (moulded case circuit breaker) is used as a main incomer which has silver plated copper terminals. The aluminium busbars are used as a conductors. While reading the IEC 60943 standard, however, I came across the anodic index of aluminium when used with respect to silver. As per the standard, the galvanic cell creates a potential difference of 770 mV which is greater than the threshold of 350 mV.

[image]

While several industrial panels and switchgear recommend to use silver plated aluminium, some do not recommend it. The current scenario uses a 630 A MCCB where the elevated temperature levels may reach 105 C. I have even [read](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/142896) that galvanic corrosion is aggravated when the temperature reaches elevated level.

Is it really okay to connect the aluminium busbar to the MCCB (silver plated copper) terminals?

If yes, is there any concrete standard to prove this, or is there any standard that recommends to conduct a test to evaluate the joints susceptible to galvanic corrosion?

I have read this [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/197830/under-what-circumstances-is-galvanic-corrosion-a-concern-in-electrical-work), but it doesn't answer my question.

Also almost all the manufacturers recommend to use tin plating, but tin with silver leads to potential difference of 470 mV which is greater than the 350 mV threshold value as per the aforementioned standard. Please note that we use contact aid compound such as petroleum jelly which to some extent halts the corrosion.

Please note that this question is been migrated from the home improvement site.

[image: Please note that the aluminium busbar (sleeved with color shrinks) are connected to silver-plated spreaders]

Adding an image of reference to IEC 61439-2 regarding operating humidity conditions:

[image]

Comment: @DaSnipeKid There are two situations that have bothered me in the past, which makes your question (to my mind) a good one to worry about. But I don't have the experience to say. Hopefully, an expert on this topic can weigh in. But I think your question is an excellent one to ask! I'll explain why in two cases within my experience.

Comment: @DaSnipeKid Case 1: NEC electrical code allows a builder to place a bare #4 copper wire, 20' in length, in a concrete foundation for a house and to use it as a Ufer ground. It also allows a similar use of 1/2" rebar, also 20' long. The problem is when using rebar in concrete and using bare #4 copper for the Ufer. Since concrete is a wet sponge, this guarantees corrosion. Such corrosion is well documented in the case of plumbing systems where a copper pipe is in galvanic association with an iron/steel pipe. Why the NEC code allows this is beyond me. It's convenient, perhaps, but stupid.

Comment: @DaSnipeKid Case 2: Copper bus bars were having to be replaced every couple of years at an installation in Idaho. The electrician on-site asked me, over a phone call, what could possibly account for such behavior. It took me just a few seconds to ask, "Is there a smelter operation nearby?" He immediately said "Yes! How did you guess that?" I said, "I had no real idea. But the only idea readily at hand would be very high circulating ground currents generating large voltage differentials to plate away the copper. So I asked." Anyway, +1. Hopefully, a serious expert can offer their thoughts.

Comment: @periblepsis, For the rebar and copper connection, there is a greater probability of galvanic corrosion taking place. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: @DaSnipeKid Agreed. Regardless, I think you present a question that needs to be addressed by someone with experience and training in this area. It's an excellent presentation demanding a good answer, I think.

Comment: I'm gonna go with a laymans rant here: Just metal to metal contact doesn't impose galvanic corrosion. It's when moisture together with impurities and oxygen that galvanic magic starts to happen. You mentioned "I have even read that galvanic corrosion is aggravated at higher temps", yes, if you have that electrolyte present. But what happens with water at higher temperature then ambient? Now, this is a speculatiion, and a comment. Take it for what it is, but maybe it'll take you into a direction where you find the proper answer.

Comment: The main issue is that once corrosion starts (say due to one off condensation after AC failure), the salts produced are generally hygroscopic.  This will lead to an active electrolyte even in seemingly "dry" conditions, as they extract moisture from the air, even above the dew point.  Very much like the way sugary cola (unlike diet) never really dries, but instead forms a syrup.

Comment: @MiNiMe, to answer your question, the temperature of the terminals of MCCB may reach 115, provided it is fully loaded. But, this is not the case considering the diversity factor and selectivity and trip settings. The breaker is 'normally' loaded at 80% of it's rated value, at which the water film formation does not vaporize owing to the less temperature. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I work in Telco and from time to time come across Al busbars in exchanges/central offices.

The Telcordia and regional standards all require the use of bimetal lugs when bolting on dissimilar cables due to corrosion risk.  Plating (as opposed to much thicker "cladding") is generally not a solution, as it is too thin to reliably prevent issues.

Cu cable/Al busbar lugs exist but are hard to obtain, so Al cables are normally used. In fact Al busbars are most common when all the cables are Al, as they mean you can use cheaper single metal Al crimps.

The reverse (Cu busbar, Al cable) is much more common as Al is often used as the conductor for larger cables, so those lugs are fairly easy to source.

Examples of fittings for Al cable to Cu busbars can be found on many supplier websites including
[TE](https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-CAT-VCXI.html) [image] and [Cembre](https://products.cembre.com/en/uk-ireland/family/1865) [image]

The lugs are produced by a friction welding process, which ensures a permanent, corrosion free, joint between the two metals.

This [article](https://codecheck.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Tech-Aluminum-Wire-Feb-2009-Print-Version.pdf) gives a good summary of the issues experienced in US domestic settings as a result of the use of Al conductors without suitable bimetal connectors, and includes a number of onward links.

You can also easily do a web search to find regional standard disallowing direct bolting without special connectors, for example [here](https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/irc-2021/chapter/34/general-requirements#E3406.8) is a link to Colorado code.

I would **not** recommend direct Cu/Al bolting (irrespective of plating) unless explicitly covered by the applicable standard. (Some standards do allow direct bolting, but with very specific prep, anti-oxidants, and operating conditions.)

In general such joints should be done using code compliant bimetal connectors.

**Extension**
Having done further research, it is clear that the joint instability of bolted Al/Cu joints is not solely dependent on the presence of moisture.

This paper:

M. Oberst, S. Schlegel and S. Großmann, "On the Aging of Electrical Joints with a Copper and an Aluminum Contact Member," 2019 IEEE Holm Conference on Electrical Contacts, Milwaukee, WI, USA, 2019, pp. 1-8, doi: 10.1109/HOLM.2019.8923935.

has an excellent analysis of causes of joint failure, and suggests that simple oxygen penetration is sufficient, especially at elevated temperature. It also suggests the issue is strongly non-linear, with localised heating leading to potential runaway failure after a long period of apparently good operation. This fits with my own experience of poor Cu crimps (from a misadjusted machine), where once resistance starts increasing, localised heating makes it much worse.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Since, the code does provide the recommendd connection, is there any standard which specifies the test to be carried out to evaluate the galvanic corrosion. One that I know of is ASTM G71-81(2019), but it does not mentions the duration of salt bath or natural air exposure.

Comment: Given my background, most of the work I've done references Telcordia GR63. This defines a wide range of physical factors from halogens and oxygen content, to resistance to hydroscopic dust and acid sprays. The main standard is very expensive, but worth looking at some of the standards for the baby bell operating companies (Qwest in particular).

Comment: This one is a good start https://www.centurylink.com/techpub/77350/77350.pdf as it includes a section on jointing

Comment: Just added an extra ref to research saying joint failure can occur simply due to oxygen penetration rather than needing water.

Comment: I think I have got the catch. The standard for switchboard 61439-1 says, that the installation site should have the 95% relative humidity when the ambient temperature ranges from -2 to +30C (Indoor switchgear). However, this means that the there wont be any condensation of water at this RH. Ultimately, due to the absence of water film, there wont be galvanic corrosion, as IEC 60943 says there should an electrolyte present for corrosion to take place. Thus, galvanic corrosion wont take place. Is my understanding correct, regarding RH and condensed water to form on surface ?

Comment: For proper "galvanic" corrosion with electrolyte, I agree.  

However, see the extension I've added to main answer about stability of simple "dry" copper/aluminum joints.  I've spoken with our power wiring team for data centres, and they view bolted/crimped copper/aluminium joints as long term unstable even if dry (due to oxide film formation), and always use bimetal connectors for terminating Al cable on Cu busbars.

Comment: For a definitive answer, I would contact tech support for the board provider, and ask if they warrant their boards with the setup you are using.

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed answer

Comment: Glad to help.  At the power levels you are dealing with, it is well worth getting this kind of thing right.  Especially as getting it wrong is a timebomb - works for years, then one day starts overheating and this can quickly escalate into either an open circuit, or more commonly destruction of the MCB.  

I've seen an under-torqued copper connector generate enough heat to melt off cable insulation several years after installation, and adding a copper/aluminum joint is just going to make it more of an issue.

Answer (score 2):

First question: Is the MCCB already supplied, or can it be changed?  Perhaps the terminals can be changed out for more suitable material if the MCCB is already existing, most MCCB OEMs supply many different terminal options.  Please confirm MCCB terminals are silver-plated, rather than tin-plated.  Beware that silver grows whiskers faster than tin in some circumstances, refer:
https://simpliengineering.com/t/silver-plated-versus-tin-plated-copper-bus/1228

Also, is the switchboard with Alu bus bars already existing?  If not, then suggest select bus-bar material to suit the MCCB terminals.

If both the alu bus-bars & the MCCB cannot be changed, then suggest connecting MCCB to Alu bar using flexible Cu cables terminated with correct lugs at each end to suit the material interface, ie: Cu cable to Alu bar at the bus-bar end, or Cu cable to silver/tin plated Cu at the MCCB end.

You may already be aware that Alu requires special preparation and treatment with oxygen barrier compounds to ensure a good connection free from oxidation, but I just thought I'd mention that to be sure.   Given this, I would think it much easier to fit a bi-metal lug at the end of a flexible cable to an Alu rigid bar, rather than fit a rigid MCCB terminal to an Alu rigid bar, while maintaining an oxidation-free connection.